# How to get gradle build type when building Android application

Tags: android, gradle, build

I have a gradle build file which has Debug and Release configurations.
During the build, I execute a task in which I need the build type. I can send arguments to the script file, but I don't know how I can get the build type in the gradle task which is running.

Comment: I think you can pass build type as a parameter to your task.
``` debug { task('debug') } 
release { task'('release') } ```

Comment: "During the build, I execute a task in which I need the build type" -- then create N tasks, one per build type. "I don't know how I can get the build type in the gradle task which is running" -- there is no such concept in Gradle.